# chef recipe dependencies - berkshelf

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, berkshelf

I use chef-server to manage my servers and am not trying to get the semi [official logstash cookbook](https://github.com/lusis/chef-logstash) working but am having trobule with recipe dependencies.

I have all my cookbooks inside a chef-config repo along with the logstash one I cloned.

```
/chef-repo
  /cookbooks
    /mysql
    /ngnix
    /logstash - https://github.com/lusis/chef-logstash
```

I need to install the recipes which logstash which depends upon, this can be done with berkshelf, however berks install puts them in ~/.berkshelf/cookbooks/apache2 which seems a bit pointless as I need them in my cookbooks folder to allow me to upload them to chef-server.

I did try:

```
berks install --path /chef-repo/cookbooks
```

but this has 2 problems, first I overwrite other cookbooks of the same name (mysql) and all of my cookbooks are deleted.

How do people manage this problem?

Comment: Did cmur2's answer fix your problem?

Comment: I would like to know how to install berkshelf as I am facing the issue

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want specify two folders containing your coobkooks for chef, one with your cookbooks and another for foreign cookbooks.